# Why does Chrome Local Storage show no records when it definitely contains data?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web app that uses LocalStorage.  While debugging, I often rely on Chrome's Dev Tools to review data in LocalStorage.  Recently, the LocalStorage panel started presenting nothing; however, if I use the console to log a key's value I can see that storage does indeed have data.  Why would Chrome not present data in local storage?

Comment: Are you taking into account the asynchronous nature of accessing `localStorage`?

Comment: LocalStorage is synchronous.  Konrad found a bug about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://crbug.com/701413) in DevTools. Feel free to star the report to get informed about the progress and increase its priority.

Comment: Hey thanks.  I called myself looking for a bug about it before posting, but obviously looked with the wrong terms.

Comment: Thanks I was getting frustrated because of this bug.

Comment: still not fixed today